# Error PLS-00323 in package body, procedure name is correct

Tags: debugging, plsql, procedure

the follow code is getting an error PLS-00323 in two places.  The first place is on the procedure spt_save_casedetail and it says "subprogram or cursor 'spt_save_casedetail' is declared in the package specification and must be defined in the package body".  Here is the code (warning its long):

```
create or replace
package body ct_cu_act_um1_pg
is

procedure spt_save_casedetail (
p_primarymemberplanid_in      in casedetail.primarymemberplanid%type,
p_servicetypecd_in            in casedetail.servicetypecd%type,
p_notifydt_in                 in casedetail.notifydt%type,
p_assignedentityid_in         in casedetail.assignedentityid%type,
p_startdt_in                  in casedetail.startdt%type,
p_enddt_in                    in casedetail.enddt%type,
p_caretypemnemonic_in         in casedetail.caretypemnemonic%type,
p_casestatusmnemonic_in       in casedetail.casestatusmnemonic%type,
p_odsorderingproviderid_in    in casedetail.odsorderingproviderid%type,
p_sourcemnemonic_in           in casedetail.sourcemnemonic%type,
p_caseresolutionmnemonic_in   in casedetail.caseresolutionmnemonic%type,
p_odsservicingproviderid_in   in casedetail.odsservicingproviderid%type,
p_serviceitemmnemonic_in      in casedetail.serviceitemmnemonic%type,
p_providerinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.providerinnetworkind%type,
p_detailtxt_in                in casedetail.detailtxt%type,
p_odsfacilityvendorid_in      in casedetail.odsfacilityvendorid%type,
p_servicelocationcd_in        in casedetail.servicelocationcd%type,
p_facilityinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.facilityinnetworkind%type,
p_audit_user_in               in casedetail.updatedby%type,
p_return_cur_out              out sys_refcursor,
p_err_code_out                out number,
p_err_mesg_out                out varchar2)
is
v_casedetailid                casedetail.casedetailid%type;
begin
select casedetail_seq.nextval into v_casedetailid from dual;
if v_casedetailid is null
  then
    insert into casedetail
      (casedetailid,
       primarymemberplanid,
       servicetypecd,
       notifydt,
       assignedentityid,
       startdt,
       enddt,
       caretypemnemonic,
       casestatusmnemonic,
       odsorderingproviderid,
       sourcemnemonic,
       caseresolutionmnemonic,
       odsservicingproviderid,
       serviceitemmnemonic,
       providerinnetworkind,
       detailtxt,
       odsfacilityvendorid,
       servicelocationcd,
       facilityinnetworkind)
    values
      (casedetail_seq.nextval,
       p_primarymemberplanid_in,
       p_servicetypecd_in,
       p_notifydt_in,
       p_assignedentityid_in,
       p_startdt_in,
       p_enddt_in,
       p_caretypemnemonic_in,
       p_casestatusmnemonic_in,
       p_odsorderingproviderid_in,
       p_sourcemnemonic_in,
       p_caseresolutionmnemonic_in,
       p_odsservicingproviderid_in,
       p_serviceitemmnemonic_in,
       p_providerinnetworkind_in,
       p_detailtxt_in,
       p_odsfacilityvendorid_in,
       p_servicelocationcd_in,
       p_facilityinnetworkind_in);

    open p_return_cur_out for
      select casedetail_seq.currval
      from dual;
  else
    update casedetail
      set primarymemberplanid = p_primarymemberplanid_in,
          servicetypecd = p_servicetypecd_in,
          notifydt = p_notifydt_in,
          assignedentityid = p_assignedentityid_in,
          startdt = p_startdt_in,
          enddt = p_enddt_in,
          caretypemnemonic = p_caretypemnemonic_in,
          casestatusmnemonic = p_casestatusmnemonic_in,
          odsorderingproviderid = p_odsorderingproviderid_in,
          sourcemnemonic = p_sourcemnemonic_in,
          caseresolutionmnemonic = p_caseresolutionmnemonic_in,
          odsservicingproviderid = p_odsservicingproviderid_in,
          serviceitemmnemonic = p_serviceitemmnemonic_in,
          providerinnetworkind = p_providerinnetworkind_in,
          detailtxt = p_detailtxt_in,
          odsfacilityvendorid = p_odsfacilityvendorid_in,
          servicelocationcd = p_servicelocationcd_in,
          facilityinnetworkind = p_facilityinnetworkind_in,
          updateddt = systimestamp,
          updatedby = p_audit_user_in
      where casedetailid = v_casedetailid;

    open p_return_cur_out for
      select casedetail_seq.currval
      from dual;
end if;

p_err_code_out := 0;
exception
when others then
  p_err_code_out := -1;
  p_err_mesg_out := 'error in ct_cu_act_um1_pg.spt_save_casedetail =>'|| sqlerrm;
end spt_save_casedetail;
```

Here is the package spec:

```
create or replace
package ct_cu_act_um1_pg
is

  procedure spt_save_casedetail (
p_primarymemberplanid_in      in casedetail.primarymemberplanid%type,
p_servicetypecd_in            in casedetail.servicetypecd%type,
p_notifydt_in                 in casedetail.notifydt%type,
p_assignedentityid_in         in casedetail.assignedentityid%type,
p_startdt_in                  in casedetail.startdt%type,
p_enddt_in                    in casedetail.enddt%type,
p_caretypemnemonic_in         in casedetail.caretypemnemonic%type,
p_casestatusmnemonic_in       in casedetail.casestatusmnemonic%type,
p_odsorderingproviderid_in    in casedetail.odsorderingproviderid%type,
p_sourcemnemonic_in           in casedetail.sourcemnemonic%type,
p_caseresolutionmnemonic_in   in casedetail.caseresolutionmnemonic%type,
p_odsservicingproviderid_in   in casedetail.odsservicingproviderid%type,
p_serviceitemmnemonic_in      in casedetail.serviceitemmnemonic%type,
p_providerinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.providerinnetworkind%type,
p_detailtxt_in                in casedetail.detailtxt%type,
p_odsfacilityvendorid_in      in casedetail.odsfacilityvendorid%type,
p_servicelocationcd_in        in casedetail.servicelocationcd%type,
p_facilityinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.facilityinnetworkind%type,
p_return_cur_out              out sys_refcursor,
p_err_code_out                out number,
p_err_mesg_out                out varchar2
  );
```

The second place im getting the same error is where I defined v_casedetailid.  Ive checked to make sure everything is spelt correctly, but maybe I'm missing something because I've been looking at it for awhile.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: this either isn't a packages, or you are not showing all the code.

Comment: I have 3 other procedures, I didnt want to add unnecesary code to crowd up the screen. Here is the package beginning:

create or replace
package body ct_cu_act_um1_pg
is

Comment: Show the package spec also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure spec and body declarations do not match.

```
body:
p_facilityinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.facilityinnetworkind%type,
**p_audit_user_in               in casedetail.updatedby%type,**
p_return_cur_out              out sys_refcursor,
p_err_code_out                out number,
p_err_mesg_out                out varchar2)

spec:
**p_facilityinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.facilityinnetworkind%type,**
p_return_cur_out              out sys_refcursor,
p_err_code_out                out number,
p_err_mesg_out                out varchar2
  );
```

Comment: Ugh, I was looking at it for so long I prob kept skipping over this.  Thank you very much, this was driving me crazy.  Have a good weekend.

Comment: @LeorA, the OP has accepted an answer previously and is aware of how the process works. [It's considered crass to ask for someone to accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce) or to ask for upvotes.